# Determine position from angles

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

[image]I have the 2D position of 2 points wrt a known position (O) and 2D vectors to those points. I have 2D unit vectors to those same 2 points wrt another point (P). How do I use that information to find the position of P wrt O?

I believe that the solution involves angles determined from dot-products, but I am having a hard time recalling how the transformation works.

Comment: If I'm getting this right, I think this can be done by triangle law for vector addition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have two vectors $p_1$ and $p_2$, and a third unknown vector $p$. And you have the unit vectors $u_1 = \frac{p_1 - p}{|p_1 - p|}$ and $u_2 = \frac{p_2 - p}{|p_2 - p|}$ and want to express $p$ in terms of $p_1$, $p_2$, $u_1$, and $u_2$.

If $\alpha = \frac{1}{|p_1 - p|}$ and $\beta = \frac{1}{|p_2 - p|}$ we get the system of equations $p + \alpha u_1 = p_1 \text{ and } p + \beta u_2 = p_2$ which gives us the equation $p_1 - p_2 = \alpha u_1 - \beta u_2$.

Dotting with $u_1$ or $u_2$ we get: $u_1 \cdot (p_1 - p_2) = \alpha - \beta (u_1 \cdot u_2)$ and $u_2 \cdot (p_1 - p_2) = \alpha (u_1 \cdot u_2) - \beta $ which is two scalar equations in two unknowns. Solve for $\alpha$ and $\beta$ and you can use it to get $p$.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. I also appreciate that you took the time to draw things with straight lines.